# Что такое /24 /16 в ip-адресах?

Tags: сеть, ip

Необходимо заблокировать все адреса: 109.207.13.X то есть от 109.207.13.0 до 109.207.13.255

Прочитал что множество адресов обозначается:
так:
109.207.13.0/16
или так:
109.207.13.0/24

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно? И что означают /16 /24 ?

Comment: количество единиц в маске подсети

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`/16`, `/24` - это обозначение классов сетей.

Переписывать матчасть не буду, поэтому почитайте [здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8).

Поэкспериментировать и наглядно понять правильность понимания можно [вот тут](http://www.subnetmask.info/).

Что касается упомянутого "109.207.13.X то есть от 109.207.13.0 до 109.207.13.255", то это сеть класса C, т.е. `109.207.13.0/24` с маской подсети `255.255.255.0` (где `/24` означает представление маски в десятичной форме, а именно с ее двоичной формы записи `11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000`, т.е. маска `24` бит из возможных `32`-х, и количество возможных хостов в этой подсети, как в твоем случае, как раз `256`, т.е. от `0` до `255` включительно).

Эх.. Раз пошла такая пьянка - режь последний огурец..

Итак, что такое `/24`: IP адрес (IPv4) представляет собой адрес, состоящий из 4 байтов (32-х бит, т.е. 4х8 бит, разделенных точкой), где его формат записи в двоичной форме выглядит как `11000000.10101000.00000000.00000001`. А десятичной форме аналогичная запись выглядит как запись из 4-х чисел от `0` до `255` включительно, где `255` - это максимальное число, которое можно выразить в 8-ми битах, т.е. `255` в двоичном формате будет выглядеть так: `11111111`. Т.е. некоторый IP, скажем `192.168.0.1`, будет выглядеть в двоичной форме так: `11000000.10101000.00000000.00000001`. Если взять сеть `192.168.0.0/24` и выбрать любой IP адрес из диапазона `192.168.0.0 - 192.168.0.255`, то для конкретного IP адреса любого из этих 256 возможных хостов (теоретически от `0` до `255` включительно) маска подсети будет выглядеть следующим образом: `11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000` (`255.255.255.0` в десятичной форме), что означает что `3х8=24` бита (слева направо) в адресе - это биты, указывающие на адрес подсети, а последние 8 битов отведены на IP адреса хостов в подсети, т.е. от `0` до `255` (что равняется `256`-ти, и `256` - это число всех возможных комбинаций от `00000000` до `11111111`).

Теперь дальше и глубже: допустим, что не требуется все `256` хостов в одной подсети, а хочется разделить пространство на еще `2` подсети (по `128` хостов в каждой). Тогда можно разделить эту сеть так: маска подсети будет `255.255.255.128` (т.е. `11111111.11111111.11111111.10000000` или же `/25` - по количеству битов слева направо) и получаем сети с `128` хостами в каждой: `0-127` в одной (Network `192.168.0.0` с Broadcast Address `192.168.0.127`) и `128-255` (Network `192.168.0.128` с Broadcast Address `192.168.0.255`) в другой.

Добавлю еще для понимания (не вдаваясь в подробности операций с двоичными данными), выражаясь простыми словами для быстрой калькуляции в уме: раз IPv4 адрес состоит всегда из `4х8=32` бит, и если маска подсети в каком-то конкретном случае занимает, скажем, `24` бит (те, что слева направо), то `32-24=8` бит идут под диапазон для IP адресов хостов (читай компьютеров, сетевых принтеров, прочих устройств, имеющих свой IPv4). И для того, чтобы посчитать в данном случае каково количество возможных хостов для каждой подсети с данной маской, то надо `2` возвести в степень `8` (где `8` - количество нулей в маске), т.е. результатом будет `256`. Если взять сеть `192.168.0.0/26`, то само собой количество нулей будет равняться `6`-ти (`32-26`), то количество хостов будет `2^6=64`, маска - `255.255.255.192`, а количество подсетей будет в данном диапазоне будет равняться `4`-м (`4х64` в каждой).

*Внимательный заметит, даже не вдаваясь в подробности, что сумма количества возможных хостов в подсети и последнее число в маске в сумме дают `256`, а количество подсетей - это `256`, разделенное на `64` (количество хостов в каждой подсети, где `256` и `64` - только для данного примера! - почему, надо понять самому, хотя бы по аналогии с`/16`, приведенным ниже) и сделает логические выводы.*

Ну и исходя из вышеперечисленного нетрудно разложить следующее: `/16` (так называемый `Class B`) - это когда возможны `65536` (`2^16`) хостов в одной подсети, т.е. маска выглядит так: `11111111.11111111.00000000.00000000`, т.е. адрес сети занимает `8х2=16` бит (слева), а под IP адреса хостов выделено тоже `8х2=16` (все возможные комбинации от `00000000.00000000` до `11111111.11111111`, т.е. как раз `65536` штук) значения бит из адреса (справа). Т.е. диапазон IP адресов хостов в десятичной форме выглядит так: от `192.168.0.0` до `192.168.255.255`, где маска подсети `/16`, т.е. `255.255.0.0`

Ну и так далее..

Что касается "Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно?" - если речь идет о `.htaccess`, то смело можете использовать `Deny` и указывать `109.207.13.0/24`.

```
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from 109.207.13.0/24
```

Если речь идет о блокировке в каких-нибудь `Cisco` или `Juniper` - то это тогда в их документацию и на РутКод :)

Comment: не надо про классы сетей пожалуйста, эта терминология устарела, /x это просто "сколько бит используется в маске" всего в IPv4 - 32 bit, поэтому, например, маска /31 указывает на первые 31 бит. маска на адрес накладывается по AND, т.е. 10101010101010101010101010101010 AND 11111111111111111111111111111100 = 10101010101010101010101010101000

Comment: Про классы упомянуто 3 раза, как раз без описания, просто для заметки. Остальная часть посвящена именно тому, чтобы на примерах показать, что такое "биты слева в маске", как они выглядят и почему это вообще так, потому что без объяснения мало кто поймет для какой цели `/31` означает количество битов. Я просто решил написать один раз и подробно, раз уж решил ответить - надеюсь, многим поможет расставить точки над `i`.
Но спасибо за объективный комментарий.